# Finding the location of half the max value in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I have a list of data frames, and I'd like to apply a function to that list to find the location in the "julian" column that corresponds to half the max value in the "total_cover" column. Here's some data that represents the data I have:

```
df1 <- data.frame(julian = c(81,85,88,97,101,104,126,167),
                  total_cover = c(43,52,75,92,94,97,188,172))
df2 <- data.frame(julian = c(81,85,88,97,101,104,126,167),
                  total_cover = c(30,55,73,80,75,85,138,154))
df3 <- data.frame(julian = c(107,111,115,119,123,129,131,133,135,137),
                  total_cover = c(36,41,43,47,55,55,55,65,75,80))

data.list <- list(df1=df1,df2=df2,df3=df3)
```

The code below is what I've tried, but I'm not getting the correct output. This doesn't seem to be finding the julian day that corresponds to half the max value

```
unlist(lapply(X = data.list, FUN = function(x){
        x[which.max(x[["total_cover"]] >= which.max(x[["total_cover"]])/2), "julian"]
}))

output:
df1  df2  df3
81   81   107
```

My ideal output would be what's shown below, with the julian dates that correspond to >= max(total_cover)/2

```
df1  df2  df3
101  97   111
```

Using R 4.2.2

Comment: Is your expected output right? For `df1` the value of `which.max(x[["total_cover"]])/2` is 3.5 so in row 3 `"julian"` is 88 and in row 4 it's 97 but you have 101, a value not in `df1$julian`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas for df1, max(df1$total_cover)/2 is 94, which is a value that exists in df1 corresponding to julian 101

Comment: OK, got it. But then in `df2` aren't there two possible values? `max(df2$total_cover)/2` is 77, a value that doesn't exist but can be between rows 3,4 or rows 5,6. This would give either the posted 97 or 104.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I'm looking to print the closest value >= to the max/2, so for df2, max(df2$total_cover)/2 = 77, of which the the closest value >= 77 is 80, corresponding to julian 97

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following answers the question.

```r
sapply(data.list, \(x) {
  half_max <- max(x$total_cover)/2
  d <- abs(x$total_cover - half_max)
  is.na(d) <- x$total_cover < half_max
  x$julian[which.min(d)]
})
#> df1 df2 df3 
#> 101  97 111
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

```
find_julian <- function(df){
  #calculate the distance from half of the maximum
  distance <- df[["total_cover"]]- max(df[["total_cover"]])/2
  #find smallest value greater than half of the maximum and select corresponding julian
  df[distance==min(distance[distance>=0]),"julian"]
}

unlist(lapply(X = data.list, FUN = find_julian))

df1 df2 df3 
101  97 111
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is step by step `dplyr` solution: The main issue is that the difference is sometimes negative and we have to remove them:

The result of

```
df1 df2 df3 
 81  81 107
```

occurs because the code does not take into consideration negative numbers!

Long version:

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(data.list, .id = 'id') %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(x = (max(total_cover)/2)) %>% 
  mutate(y = total_cover-x) %>% 
  filter(y >=0) %>% 
  filter(y == min(y)) %>% 
  select(1:2) %>% 
  pull(julian, name = id)
```

Or a little shorter:

```
bind_rows(data.list, .id = 'id') %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(total_cover-(max(total_cover)/2) >=0) %>% 
  filter(total_cover == min(total_cover)) %>% 
  select(1:2) %>% 
  pull(julian, name = id)
```

result:

```
df1 df2 df3 
101  97 111
```